# Color only some edges [jsdisplacement]

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, color, displacement

i'm using jsdisplacement to generate maps, i would like to know how can i color only some "edges" as in this [video](https://youtu.be/EsFyiQ2Rvuk?t=8m54s) ( that he color gold)

[image]

[The map i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUL0E.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide blend file with this map? You can upload it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: i don't know if the way i'm doing it is correct

Comment: because i'm using a displacement modifier insteand of doing it with nodes

Comment: You will need to pack png to the file.